# how to make the inner class properties take the values of the parent class properties?

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

my question is  how to make the inner class properties take the values of the parent class properties

```
function drawSvg(element)
{
  this.x= 0;
  this.y=0;
  this.strockeColor="#FFF";
  this.fillColor= "#000";
  this.darwCircle= function()
  {
       this.x = parent.x;//here what I have to do to make the x of  darwCircle  take the vale of  drawSvg x
  }

}
```

in my example above I do not know what is the code that I should put to do that ??

Comment: `strockeColor` is probably a typo...

Comment: I hope that `darwCircle` is not a class? How do you intend to use this code?

Comment: `drawCircle` is a method of `drawSvg`, so `this` is the same in both contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of doing this is including:

in the parent scope write

```
var self = this;
```

and in the child scope you can write

```
this.x = self.x; //now you can take the value of the parent
```

and for more clarification here is the complete example

```
function drawSvg(element)
{
    this.x= 200;
    this.y=0;
    this.strockeColor="#FFF";
    this.fillColor= "#000";
    this.lineWidth =10;
    this.set = function(x, y, strockColor, fillColor, lineWidth )
    {
        this.x= x;
        this.y= y;
        this.strockeColor= strockColor;
        this.fillColor= fillColor;
        this.lineWidth= lineWidth;
    }

    self = this;// look here 

    this.darwCircle= function()
    {
       this.x = self.x+2000; // look here 
    }
}

var d = new drawSvg("ddfds");
var dc = new d.darwCircle();
console.log(dc.x);
```

Comment: You should note that `new d.darwCircle();` is nothing that one should do.